# ArrayList becomes null after addValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to show some items in a `RecyclerView` and such items are contained in an `ArrayList` populated with `RealtimeDatabase` (Firebase) data. This is done every time some changes are detected in the db as follows. The problem is that `lstCompany` becomes null soon after the `addValueEventListener`. How can I keep it fulfilled?

```
public class FragmentCompanies extends Fragment {
    View v;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Company> lstCompany;
    DatabaseReference db;

    public FragmentCompanies(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                lstCompany = new ArrayList<>();
                DataSnapshot ds = dataSnapshot.child("Company");
                for (DataSnapshot company: ds.getChildren()){
                    Map<String, String> currCompany = (Map) company.getValue();
                    Company c = new Company(currCompany.get("name"), currCompany.get("overview"), currCompany.get("imageURL"));
                    lstCompany.add(c);
                    System.out.println(lstCompany);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        System.out.println(lstCompany);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_companies,container,false);

        System.out.println(lstCompany);

        //bind the adapter to the recyclerView
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.companies_recyclerview);
        CompaniesRecyAdapter recyAdapter = new CompaniesRecyAdapter(getContext(), lstCompany);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyAdapter);

        return v;
    }
}
```

The last two `println` operations return null and it should not happen.

Comment: That's a callback. `lstCompany` is null outside of your `ValueEventListener` because `onDataChange` hasn't been called yet.

Comment: True, thanks for the explanation. But how can I make the RecyclerView update each time the data in the database changes? Consider that the callback is needed because of Firebase db...

Comment: Can't you call whatever update you need from `onDataChange`? That's what callbacks are for...

Answer (score 1):

intialize the arraylist in onCreate, and when add data in on onDataChange and notify the adapter that data has been changed

```
public class FragmentCompanies extends Fragment {
    View v;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Company> lstCompany;
    DatabaseReference db;
    public FragmentCompanies(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_companies,container,false);

        lstCompany = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(lstCompany);

        //bind the adapter to the recyclerView
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.companies_recyclerview);
        CompaniesRecyAdapter recyAdapter = new CompaniesRecyAdapter(getContext(), lstCompany);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyAdapter);

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot ds = dataSnapshot.child("Company");
                for (DataSnapshot company: ds.getChildren()){
                    Map<String, String> currCompany = (Map) company.getValue();
                    Company c = new Company(currCompany.get("name"), currCompany.get("overview"), currCompany.get("imageURL"));
                    lstCompany.add(c);
                    System.out.println(lstCompany);
                    System.out.println(c.getCompanyName);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        System.out.println(lstCompany);





        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the last two prints return []

Comment: try to print its size  lstCompany.size()
You can  not print a list like that

Comment: size is obviously 0

Comment: inside for loop try to print c.compantname, run if it is printing anything or not

Comment: I simply added the notify operation for the adapter after the for cycle and it seems it worked (I know it was written at the beginning but I misunderstood the sentence, as it's my first time handling RecyclerViews...). Thank you!